# Scores on tag specific badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

Here I have two suggestions on tag specific badges,

1. To get tag specific badges you should get 400 or 1000 upvote on a specific tag. You can see how much score you did on a tag when you click on a tag, at stats panel.

   I think it would be great if we can see our score at our profile, or can we see them somewhere else ?
2. Accepted answers seems like have no effect on users score on a tag. In my opinion they should have a score point.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 5):

1. This was asked for a while back and Jeff replied that a query like that would be to heavy to be used regularly (by a user that is). Since you theoretically could see your score for every tag. (which goes through every tag and gets your upvotes)
2. Accepting an answer gives 15 in rep. It does not give an upvote. I think the query that asks for this information is slow enough than to slow it even further by calculating in accepted scores.

Comment: I know the stats page is so slow but is it all because of this ? Interesting.

Comment: I think the stats page is slow because while top 20(?) can be cached it also returns your stats for that tag so you can see where you are in relation to everyone else. That can't be cached (obviously) - hence the lack of speed.

Comment: Surely the "a query like that" must be run routinely to award the badge in the first place..?

Answer (score 2):

The "heavy query" logic makes sense, unfortunately. Still, it the stats were on a tab other than the default, most users wouldn't be hitting it all the time.

Perhaps a good balance is to just grab a user's score for their top 3-5 tags, and have a link to load more detail?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this happening.. From ["Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101):

> Badges are supposed to incite curiosity about why the badge exists and what you did that caused you to earn it.
>
> As I've said umpteen zillion times, this is based on the Xbox 360 Achievements model. You see the achievement flash on screen..
>
> [image]
>
> .. and then you go figure it out.

Showing "you are __% close to this badge" kind of ruins the fun/surprise..

You can always use the [data dump](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if you *really* want to know!

Comment: Playing Gears of War, you can see how many more human shields you need for a meatbag.

Comment: World of Warcraft has a pretty extensive list of achievements, each of which you can see current progress and objectives.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of new users accept answers without upvoting. A lot of these questions are very specific to the user's problem, for example "what is wrong with my config file". There is very little chance that this will be of interest to another user.

Therefore, I think that an accepted answer should count towards a badge tag.