# Do accepted answers without upvote count towards tag specific badges?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, accepted-answer

When an answer is accepted but not upvoted, does that count towards progress of a tag badge?

> [image: tag-badge]

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/467/scores-on-tag-specific-badges) from 2009 overlaps, indicating no effect on accepted answers; however, is between a feature request and discussion of query performance.

At first, it seemed reasonable that only an upvote would count toward progress; however, it seems that an accepted answer is almost a stronger statement than simply upvoting something.

Even per reputation, an accepted answer is valued at +15 reputation vs upvote at +10.

Comment: They count the same as other unupvoted answers. So if your score is high enough, they count for the number of required answers (except CW).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accepted answers are not taken into account at all for the tag badges. Only votes (upvotes increase your tag score by one, downvotes decrease it by one too).

(This is explained in the [badge faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395) and the [tag badge faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836).)

I believe part of the reasoning for not counting the accept as a score here is that the accept is the OPs choice, and the OP might not be the best judge of the technical merits of the post - after all, they didn't know how to do it before you answered :-)

Also the OP could both upvote (with sufficient rep) and accept, and that would count not only as more than two upvotes in terms of rep, but two tag points too.

You should see the accept checkmark as a "Thank you!" from the OP that comes with a nice bonus in rep, nothing else.