# Show the tag(s) for which a user earned Taxonomist

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, taxonomist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

Is it possible to show what tag someone got the Taxonomist (and whatever other badges that are tag-related) badge for?

Comment: This has already been proposed and declined by Jeff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge

Comment: This is now actually __completed__ (for anyone who stops by and sees Kyle's comment and doesn't want to click through to the linked posts)