# Feature request: tell us what we got a badge for!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

I logged into Stack Overflow this morning to find that I'd been awarded the Popular Question badge, but unfortunately I have know idea what for. I could probably find out with a bit of digging, but it would be nice if the banner and Recent tab made it explicit.

Comment: Jeff has declined this feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101

Comment: Put your mouse over the badge and read the description?

Comment: @Andriod That doesn't tell me which question/answer led to getting the badge.