# Popular Questions Badge: Show Which Question is the Popular Question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

So, I was just awarded with a popular question badge.

The thing is that I don't know for which I was awarded that badge with. Is there anyway to find out? Or better, in the recent tab ( shown in above figure) show the question that was awarded with that badge.

Comment: Good luck with that! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/feature-request-tell-us-what-we-got-a-badge-for-closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [the long answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/898#898).

The short answer is that it won't be done because it couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Popular Question means it hit 1,000 views, so rank your questions by number of views and then search for the one that is the closest to 1,000. That would be the one that likely just triggered your badge.

Comment: The problem is that I have been awarded this badge numerous time and it's tough luck to find which is the latest addition

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Like I said, if you rank your questions by the number of views, and you find the one with the closest number to 1,000 (say 1001, or 1003 or something like that)...that would be a pretty clear indicator of which one was the MOST RECENT one to eclipse the 1,000 mark.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has [already decided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101) that they won't be implementing this feature.

He said:

> This is intentional and by design.
>
> Badges are supposed to incite curiosity about why the badge exists and what you did that caused you to earn it.
>
> As I've said umpteen zillion times, this is based on the Xbox 360 Achievements model. You see the achievement flash on screen..
>
> .. and then you go figure it out.
>
> **The discovery is part of the fun!**

Comment: "The discovery is part of the fun!"  That reminds me of a parent trying to get their kid to eat creamed spinach by pretending to be an airplane..."open up the hanger for the airplane!  It's fun!"  Even 2 year olds realize that this isn't actually fun.

Comment: Why on earth would I want to go "discover" something that should be readily available?

Comment: Because Jeff Atwood wants to treat us like kids. Good luck. Whenever I see a popular question badge. Yeah OK and decide not to waste any time finding out.