# Is it at all possible to find out which tag earned me the Taxonomist badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, badges, taxonomist-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who created which tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22140/who-created-which-tag)

I just got the notification telling me that I earned the Taxonomist badge. With curiosity getting the better of me, I tried to find out what badge I had created.

But [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge) you can't.

> I agree that once you have hundreds of badges the thrill of discovery probably wears off. But, do you think that is representative of the entire Stack Overflow audience? Or perhaps a very vocal minority?

There must be something I am missing. I tried looking on my profile page for something that might aid me, but there is nothing there. All it tells me is that I have *participates* in 482 tags. Next, I took a look at the [list of tags](https://superuser.com/tags?page=2). I thought maybe I could go through all the tags with 60-45 questions and see if I am the creator. Once I saw that there were about 40-or-so tags within this range, I simply gave up. Just as well, because the tag pages do not seem to tell you who the creator is.

So Jeff, I *really* wish I could find out how I got this badge. I *really*, *really* wish
I could feel this 'thrill of discovery' you keep talking about when discussing this issue, but it appears impossible to discover this at all, let alone in a 'thrilling' way.

It's like going hunting, but all the animals are already dead.

[image: duck hunt]

Comment: this feature would also be great for tons of badges, like figuring out which answer earned you that "good answer" badge (although its a little more obvious)

Comment: I am not necessarily after finding out what questions/tag/badge/comment awarded you the badge, all I am really concerned about is finding the creator of a given tag, or listing any tags i have created. Then at least i could experience this "thrill of discovery"

Comment: From everything I've seen, Jeff is adamant that this isn't going to happen. Personally I think it's a pity, but it's not a huge deal.

Comment: Any updates to this, half a year later?  I am in the enviable position of having gotten the taxonomist badge on SU, and I really want to know why I got it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/7868) was the first to have the [filesystems tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filesystems). There is one earlier question with this tag, but the tag wasn't added until [later](https://superuser.com/revisions/6769/list).

As for how to figure this out, when you receive the notification, likely it was recently that the tag went from less than 50 to equal or greater, so look through the tags with about 50 questions (much much easier on SU than SO) and look through the first questions asked with that tag. Also, be aware of revision history and migrated questions, because sometimes the oldest questions are not actually the ones who had the tag first. This is surely not a completely accurate process, and can be time-consuming, but generally, especially when you're searching for it right after receiving the badge, its possible to figure it out.

Comment: Well at least it is possible, in a round-a-bout kind of way.

Answer (score 3):

It's been made possible now that the [badging system tells you what you badged up for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge).

- [Stack Overflow Taxonomists](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist)
- [Server Fault Taxonomists](https://serverfault.com/badges/11/taxonomist)
- [Super User Taxonomists](https://superuser.com/badges/11/taxonomist)

Answer (score 1):

I have to tell you that *[it's not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11881/popular-questions-badge-show-which-question-is-the-popular-question)* to discover which question brings in what tags.

Because [it's not technically possible now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/898#898).

Sorry.

Comment: Right, "not technically possible". That answer just says that it isn't implemented at the moment (which isn't so surprising for a feature request). It also says "We won't implement it because you better believe me that it's fun, and if you disagree, get lost."

Comment: How does the taxonomist badge awarder work then? With a separate datamodel or so? It has to got the information from *somewhere?*

Comment: @BalusC: There's [data not in the datadump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased/52217#52217).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of resolving this is simply to identify the tag's creator in the tag directory. At least then there's a hope that a user can find their name (and the badges they created)...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't this be done with the data dump?

Sort questions by post time. Mark tags when they first appear, give that credit to the user. Highlight tags used more than 50 times?

Sounds like an easy query to me.

Comment: Not as easy as it first appears.  You get credited with creating a tag whenever that tag is first used (i.e. you ask a question with it *or* you retag to add it), even if the tag is later deleted from the first place it was used.  (AFAIK)

Comment: The data dump, IIRC, does not remember previous edits, only the latest edit.