# Is the taxonomist badge been awarded *immediately* when the tag is been used for 50th time?

Tags: support, taxonomist-badge

I just received the `taxonomist` badge at SO. This was a surprise because the only tag which I remember I created was `[ie6-ie7-bug]` which is at 33 questions now.

Out of curiousity I immediately went to the [tags page 55](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=55) where (currently) all tags with 50 questions are visible. I scanned every tag with 50 questions and sorted questions on `active` to check which question was active within 24 hours ago. If there was one, I also verified the last question in the list as well if the activity happened within in the time I was myself also active at SO (after 1 November 2009).

The only tag which was in the range was the [`[ie8]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie8). I for sure haven't created it, since it [should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47664/tag-merge-request-internet-explorer-related-tags) have been `[internet-explorer-8]`.

So before further investigating (yes, I want to know which tag it is! ;) ), I'd like to know *when* the badge will be awarded? Does it happen *immediately* or maybe (more than) 24 hours later after the 50th use?

Comment: Even assuming it's awarded immediately, a retag may have pushed the count to 60 or higher.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it at all possible to find out which tag earned me the Taxonomist badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26370/is-it-at-all-possible-to-find-out-which-tag-earned-me-the-taxonomist-badge)

Comment: There are a lot of dupes related to "Which tag earned me Taxonomist?" but no one actually answers *when* it's been awarded. Directly after 50th use? Or later? If so, how long about? For me that's enough info to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one as a result of a mass retag, and it was awarded within a few minutes.

Comment: OK, within a few minutes. Thank you. The "mass retag" doesn't make me happy to continue the journey... ;) However... It's still a surprise. I was always been careful when choosing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with the new (great!!!) feature which displays more detailed information about the badges which you earned, it appears that it **is** actually the `[ie8]` tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?user_id=157882

This confirms my initial suspicion. I am a bit overwhelmed. Did I really create that? Unawarely? I checked the edit history of every question and I didn't find any evidence that I retagged the question with that tag.

Comment: You might have created it on a question that has since been retagged internet-explorer-8.