# How do I find out which question/answer earned me a badge?

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

I click on the little envelope.

It tells me that I have earned one badge, so I click on the "1".

It tells me I earned a "Popular Question Badge" but how do I find out which question earned me that badge?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104/is-there-any-way-to-enable-code-completion-for-perl-in-vim

Comment: Technically this is [status-completed] now ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only way would be to look through your question and check the view count and see which one went over the level for a popular question (1,000 views I believe).

Based on your StackOverflow account, I can see why that wouldn't be very efficient. In your case, you might want to rank them according to Views and see the one that is CLOSEST to 1,000. This should point you to the one that just passed over the 1,000 threshold.

I agree that there should be a better way of tracking what questions and answers earn some badges. It would cut down on the amount of time taken out to actually hunt them down.

Comment: Jeff appears to be firmly convinced that attempting to figure these things out in a Sherlock-Holmes-type fashion is one of the most fun things possible about SO, maybe *the* funnest *ever*.