# On badges and Necromancers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [is there a way to know which question / answer is linked to a badge on my own profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23858/is-there-a-way-to-know-which-question-answer-is-linked-to-a-badge-on-my-own-pro)
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)
>   [How do I find out which question/answer earned me a badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/how-do-i-find-out-which-question-answer-earned-me-a-badge)

I just noticed that I got the Necromancer badge on SO. Given the amount of questions that I have answered, its going to take a while to figure out just what answer earned it.

Could badges in the user page (when clicked) point to questions / answers that earned them rather than everyone else who has earned the badge?

I'd really like to know what answer earned it. Sifting though 200+ answers to figure it out makes my curiosity dwindle in a very rapid fashion.

Comment: Dup of many other questions. Basically it doesn't fit in with Jeff's idea of why badges are fun...

Comment: For some reason I read this at first as "Badgers and Necromancers"

Comment: mmmm, badgers....

Comment: mmmmm, mushrooms

Comment: snakes!               ..........