# How about adding links to questions in the 'Recent Badges' section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, homepage

Sometimes I'll notice a 'Great Question' or similar in the 'Recent Badges' section of the homepage and wonder what it was for. Occasionally curiosity will get the better of me, and I'll track down the question/answer on the users profile. but I thought it might be a good idea certain badges would link to the specific question/answer which caused them.

The Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer tags make good candidates, but perhaps we could include Favorite/Stellar Questions and the like as well.

Does anyone else think this could be useful?

Also, as an aside, I sort of think badges like Woot/Enthusiast, Fanatic, and Yearling shouldn't be listed in the 'Recent Badges' section. It seems like more than half of the badges listed are one of the three anytime I look at that section of the page.

Comment: Sounds like you want to find out which Q|A got you the badge: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge - And you have a thing against the sponsor, like this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/maybe-not-show-enthusiast-badge-on-the-sidebar

Comment: @random: I don't have a thing against the sponsor at all. I do, hopefully understandably, have a thing against a large portion of that section being dominated by these three badges which are basically "I like this website!" badges rather than some achievement. I just checked, and 18/32 of the badges listed were one of these three. Seems like a lot of noise with not enough signal.

Comment: I also checked the semi-duplicate question (though for *my own* questions, my recent activity page makes things fairly obvious), which I didn't find before I posted this question. I'm not at all impressed with Jeff's "GTFO my site" attitude on that question, but it does make it obvious this question will go nowhere. Even a response from Jon Skeet didn't help things, so what hope would a nobody like me have.

Comment: The lots-and-lots of Enthusiast and Fanatic badges situation is partially the result of the badges being pretty new, and will settle out as all of the only term active users get them. Then the only traffic on those badges will be *new* active users.

Answer (score 1):

This has come up many times before - see [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

As [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) says:

> This is intentional and by design.
>
> Badges are supposed to incite
>   curiosity about why the badge exists
>   and what you did that caused you to
>   earn it.
>
> As I've said umpteen zillion times,
>   this is based on the Xbox 360
>   Achievements model. You see the
>   achievement flash on screen..
>
> .. and then you go figure it out.
>
> The discovery is part of the fun!

I think you're asking about *other people's* badges, but I think the same reasoning applies (especially as your own badges are listed under that section too).