# StackQL: Yet Another Data Dump Sandbox

Tags: discussion, data-dump, stackql

StackQL <strike>is</strike>was a direct-query site for the public data dump.

Like the [original](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/), JavaScript is required, and it's limited to 1000 rows in the result set. (You can bust out of that if you know how, but all queries are logged, and so I'll see it and block anyone caught abusing things too much). There's also a query governor to restrict any really expensive queries, but it should be set high enough right now to let most things through.

What distinguishes this from [StatOverflow](http://statoverflow.com/) is that I'm on the October data release rather than July, I'm running **[SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005)** rather than [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) 5 (with [Brent Ozar's schema](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/how-to-import-the-stackoverflow-xml-into-sql-server/)). Also, I'm using the Telerik controls provided to 10K users (an excuse to try them out was one of the reasons for the building this in the first place).

Thanks to the generosity of Mr DailyWTF himself, Alex Papadimoulis, StackQL is now running on a hosted machine with a *much* better connection. You can now access it here:

> #### http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/

#### Features:

- Schema dropdown menus in the toolbar to help jog your memory for table and column names (click one, and it's inserted directly into the text)
- Basic client-side sorting
- Logs table to show what others are looking at
- Better error messages in most cases (a few errors will still sometimes just say "no results returned")
- The <kbd>F5</kbd> key give you a chance to cancel before re-submitting (you won't lose changed query text)
- Resize/remove columns
- Did not HTML encode post bodies, so formatting is at least partially preserved
- Export to CSV (URL encode the query and pass it to `quick.ashx?q=<your%20urlencoded%20query%20here>`)

#### Notes on the Logs table:

- I left it out of the dropdown lists on purpose
- Right now it's mostly just my test queries: make sure the system works, make sure the logs table is visible, etc.
- The QueryHash column uses an [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash, but before taking the hash I convert the query to all uppercase and standardize whitespacing, in an effort to try to group together identical queries that may differ only by formatting.
- Yes, this means all your vanity searches are visible to everyone.
- An MD5 hash of your [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) is logged (not the IP address itself). That column doesn't show up by default if you just do a select * from logs, but I don't want anyone to be surprised that it's there or that you can query on it. If anyone can convince me this is a huge problem I might be willing to change how it works.

#### Notes on the Telerik controls (because I know some will be curious):

- I had a working proof of concept done with *no C# code at all* before even installing the controls on my system, so they weren't an enabling factor in this. Of course, I eventually did add some C# code for validation, hash generation, etc, later. But a simpler version of this site is possible using basic, out-of-the-box [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) WebForms controls with no server code.
- The controls were an interesting of mix of 'wow, that's cool' and frustration. It feels like maybe I didn't get them installed quite right, as some things that should have worked better didn't, there were rendering or JavaScript issues at times, and other odd behaviors.
- The editor definitely is not intended as a code editor, and even though there's a `.Text` property I wasn't able to get dynamic syntax highlighting working without seeing an occasional formatting tag end up in my query text. That said, it would be an *awesome* rich text editor, which is more what it's made for, and I think with more experience and time I might be able to get the syntax highlighting up (I'm not trying though).
- The controls did enable me to do a few things: Column resizing would not have worked nearly as well without the RADGrid. I'm not a graphic designer, and so having ready-made skins was helpful. Once I understood things, the editor was a big time-saver getting the drop down lists for the schema working.
- I only needed three of the controls (RADEditor, RADGrid, and RADScriptManager) for this project. There are *many* more controls included in the toolkit.
- This was my first experience with these controls, and so some blame for any lingerings issues or oddness likely lies with me rather than the controls.

#### Planned features:

- I'm really hoping to get some feedback and help making it look a little nicer, especially the banner. A black box with a white border just doesn't cut it, and I could use a better looking image to go with the logo.
- <kbd>Done</kbd><strike>I want to add a button to the result column headers that you can use for columns that are PostIDs or UserIDs use to automatically create links to the corresponding question or user profile on Stack Overflow.</strike>... Actually, I'm now leaning towards triggering this based on the column names: ends with `QuestionId`, `PostId`, or `AnswerID` and I link to the question. Ends with `UserId` and I link to the user.
- <kbd>Done</kbd>A way to link to a query for sharing
- <kbd>Done</kbd>Add a feedback link (probably point it here and let people add answers)
- <kbd>Done</kbd><strike>Add Url encode/decode buttons to editor toolbar, to support [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) export via the `quick.ashx` handler.</strike> Decided to use a "Results to CSV" button on the toolbar instead.
- <kbd>Done</kbd>Full-text indexes on Body and Title columns in the posts table, and comment text.
- Other indexes?
- Other ideas welcome.

#### Known bugs:

- If you allow your session to expire, viewstate validation will fail and you'll get a yellow screen of death. Need to catch that and just reset the viewstate. Turning off viewstate validation doesn't help.
- Some weird un-reproducable JavaScript weirdness from time to time.
- Query governor and certain other errors just report 'no results returned' rather than an error
- Newlines are lost in the query logs
- HTML isn't stripped from pasted queries correctly
- Please let me know if you find others.

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Showing the entire post body can be nice, but it makes result lists very long.

Comment: Also, I know horizontal scrolling can be a pain, I would like to see it here so I can show wider columns.

Comment: It helps if you resize the column, and if you don't want the entire thing you can trim it in your sql code.

Comment: Well, I'm prolly not the best beta tester as I have a very limited knowledge of SQL.

Comment: It needs a way to link to a query for sharing.

Comment: @Joel: Why there's no `Score` column in the `Comments` table?

Comment: I hadn't noticed it was missing.  I used the stored procedures posted by brent ozar after the first release to create the database, so I'm guessing those procedures weren't looking for a score column.  Unfortunately, I'm not inclined to change the database until after next month's release.

Comment: I am amazed at the number of queries I've seen where people tried to use _mysql_ syntax rather than sql server.  Things like unix timestamps, limit 100, backtick column names, and more.  This SQL SERVER people.  It's say T-SQL right up there at the top of the page.

Comment: This is pretty cool, but can you get this hosted somewhere? It takes like 30 seconds to load the page from where I am.

Comment: @Joel: i'm probably one of them - nearly all the queries i have handy for SO are targeting StatOverflow (and thus, MySQL) - it's easier to just paste and look for errors than it is to try remembering what's different (stupid SqlServer limit limitations...)
Hey, look on the bright side: if it wasn't for StatOverflow, i'd be throwing SQLite queries at it...

Comment: Kyle: unfortunately I don't have anywhere else to put it, but I'll share the code if anyone can come up with a host for it.  Also: I applied several updates through the day and since I just announced it today it's likely taking more traffic right now than it will later on: trying checking again in a few days.

Comment: @Joel: After waiting a few hours it seems to be much more responsive. I did discover a minor bug - the sorting seems to be text based, even on columns of numbers. Would it be possible to look at the type of the column and use that to direct the kind of sort that's done?

Comment: ...hmm, the Id column seems to be sorting properly... To give you a better idea of the issue I'm having, run a query on the comments table and sort by PostId and UserId

Comment: ...and when I say "sort", I mean use the client-side Telerik sorting. How I wish I could edit comments ;-)

Comment: Actually, I couldn't get the client-side sort working using the telerik control. It wants to post back to the server each time you sort.  So this sorter is one of my own creation, and it should detect a numeric column... I'll have to look at it.

Comment: Ah, figured out why the sorting wasn't happening as expected.  It uses the first row to guess the data type for each question.  If you have a null value in a column at the top (say, for a column like parentid or acceptedanswerid) it won't know how to sort it and just fall back to the default.

Comment: Also: moving to the new server gave me a chance to fix the comments table. It now includes the score column.

Comment: From the screenshot below it wasn't always like that, but right now you have a double "in" in your subtitle.

Comment: Is the site down?  I cannot connect to this URL (using Chrome 3).  Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @Joel -- have you given up on this?  I get an administrator login panel when I attempt to access the site.

Comment: @tvanfosson - check here: http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/ It's a slow machine with no indexes, but it works 'til I have new hosting ready.

Comment: @Joel, any reason not to edit that URL into the question?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to have to clean up all the links to my testing site later.  But this one is probably worth it, so I made the edit.

Comment: Ugh, how did I miss that one? :(

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Are you still maintaining this? Looks like all links are dead now.

Comment: @AnnaLear Sadly I am not able to keep it online. It ran on a "server" running on an old Atom cpu that ran out of my home ISP. It was fun, but now that we have data explorer and since I've moved a few times since, I can't keep it online anymore. I do still have all of the data, so I've considered going back through and finding old links to re-point to data explorer, but that's a big job. I could provide an export of the queries matched to the ID number easily enough. This gives me the idea: I can post that as a meta question asking for volunteers to help fix old links.

Comment: @AnnaLear I take that back: I have some of the data. Some of it was hosted on a server donated by the DailyWTF guy, and part of the reason StackQL died was I had a hard time getting reliable access to that server for updates. Some of the data died with it.

Comment: Hmm... maybe not that large of a job after all: only 18 posts found. http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/revision/103993/126395/posts-linking-to-stackql

Comment: Better link: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/104022/posts-linking-to-stackql

Comment: Okay, confident those 18 results go away the next time Data Explorer refreshes. Now on to comments: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/104088/comments-linking-to-stackql They will have to wait for another day, though.

Comment: Oh, so my IP address isn't stored, but an MD5 hash of it is? Now I feel so much safer!

Answer (score 2):

> via Isaac Waller:

It needs a way to link to a query for sharing

Comment: Good idea.  I'm torn: should I add an identity column to the logs table or use the query hash as the key?  Probably the former, since the query hash is by design not unique.  From there I can just start checking a querystring param for the log id if (!IsPostBack) and using that for the query text.

Comment: Then I need to show the log id somewhere in the interface as a permalink.  Any ideas where to put it?

Comment: Id column is now added to the logs table and populated, so step one finished.

Comment: Sorry        :(

Comment: Loading the link via querystring parameter works as well (qid).  Now just need to show the link when you run the query.

Comment: Updated StackQL this evening; the link shows in a the new version.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be *great* if i could pass a query in a querystring, and get a clean table of results back as a response (no AJAX)!

This'd let me suck query results into a Google Docs spreadsheet, create forms for stuffing parameters into queries,and produce graphs and such.

Comment: I'll look into it. Probably build a new page for that, you'll have to urlencode your query, blah blah blah

Comment: Check this url: http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/StackQL/quick.ashx?q=select%20id%2CBody%20from%20posts

Comment: Works: http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AnuSKH8sLqgjdHdSVzRIVkVYSGZWQW5YSUtyOTkxOHc&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

#### Cookies

Tried in Opera, but wasn't able to get anything of a screen. Just the blank. Then figured it might be cookies/sessions. So it goes. Will it only spit back if you have cookies-allow?

#### Old stuff below:

At first it was like trying to query this:

```
SELECT ans.ParentId as QuestionID, ans.Score, qs.Title
FROM posts as ans
INNER JOIN posts as qs 
ON ans.ParentId=qs.Id
WHERE ans.PostTypeId='2' and 
      ans.OwnerUserId='23354' and 
      ans.Score > '4' and 
      (ans.CreationDate - qs.CreationDate) > '5097600'
ORDER BY ans.CreationDate DESC
```

But then it was like:

> No records to display.

Which given that it [ran on the Stat Overflow Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/is-there-a-good-way-of-looking-up-the-cause-of-another-users-badge), is missing out on two rows at least. Is it case sensitive? No maths allowed?

Honestly thought that the Run Query button was for the Media Player to stream some radio.

[image: break the sql]

Seriously, you're also missing this:

## λ

Comment: I'm sure the problem is this part: `(ans.CreationDate - qs.CreationDate) > '5097600'`.  StatOverflow uses unix timestamps.  This does not.  It is a problem with the error not being reported correctly though, and I haven't figured out how to trap those yet.

Comment: Run the query like this: `SELECT ans.ParentId as QuestionID, ans.Score, qs.Title
FROM posts as ans
INNER JOIN posts as qs 
ON ans.ParentId=qs.Id
WHERE ans.PostTypeId='2' and 
      ans.OwnerUserId='23354' and 
      ans.Score > '4'  
     and datediff(d, qs.CreationDate, ans.CreationDate) > 59
ORDER BY ans.CreationDate DESC`

Comment: And yes, that is the media player logo.  I had a limited icon set to pick from, and that one most-closely matched what I wanted to do.  Also note the "i" icon next to column: I have `ShowIcon="False"` for that button, but there it is anyway.

Comment: This raises another good question: what's appropriate music for SQL coding?

Comment: @Shog9: Heavy metal so that I can at least bash my face on the keyboard to the rhythm.

Comment: The Runtime Error isn't making for easy testing.

Comment: Back to normal now, for the time being.  "Normal" should be changing soon, for the better ;)

Comment: every time you say "Opera", god kills an angel.

Comment: Just saw the cookies note.  I have no idea: i'm pretty sure that cookie is set by one of the telerik contorls, and I'd never used them before this so I couldn't yet begin to tell you what I need to do to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a note where people will see it that I've temporarily raised the query governor limit.  A lot of queries that used an order by clause were bumping up against it, and so I raised the limit.

Note that I expect this to be temporary.  I suspect there was only a problem because the database is so new, and so there were no actual statistics to use as a base-line for cost estimates. I'll leave it up like this for week or two to establish better costs, and then run some test to see where the final number should be.

The 500 record limit on the result set remains.

Comment: this should not be an answer but an edit to the question, ditto for your other "answer"

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to export a SQL query as HTML?

Comment: What does html do for you that csv or the current grid doesn't?

Comment: I'd like to have a set of questions/answers offline occasionally, but be able to view the data in a readable format (close to the original format ideally)

Comment: I think I'm gonna decline this- since the html formatting is including inside the csv column it's easy enough to build your own offline reference from the csv data.

Answer (score 0):

Another update:

Increased command timeout to 2 minutes (it was set *far* too low) and trapped a certain class of error I was missing that should eliminate most yellow screens.