# any interesting graphs of SO user interconnectedness?

Tags: discussion, users, graphs

Has anybody used the SO db dumps to generate graphs showing how users are interconnected via their questions and answers, or related to tags?

I'm curious to see how "clumpy" people tend to be... i.e., how many people stick with one or two topics, how many answer across a broad variety of topics, etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might provide inspiration: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/499/have-we-met

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now relatively easy to make your own.

At [Shog9's request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22869/yet-another-data-dump-sandbox/22876#22876), I added a feature to [StackQL](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/) today that let's you pass in a UrlEncoded sql SELECT statement in the 'q' parameter of the `quick.ashx` query string, and get csv back out.  Apparently you can easily put that in a Google spreadsheet and generate charts from there.

An example request looks like this:

http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/StackQL/quick.ashx?q=select%20id%2CBody%20from%20posts

Comment: Since I made this answer two things have happened: One is that I updated the site so that you can just select a csv output option from a toolbar.  If you need it, the old urlencode method still works.  That's good.  The other is that the server that hosts stackql has decided to not be stable, and I haven't had time to figure out why.  That's bad, but that's the way it's gonna be for a little while.