# Data dump sandbox by RdbHost

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Rdbhost currently provides a [sandbox with the Stack Overflow dump data](http://www.rdbhost.com/rdbadmin/main.html?r0000000767).  It uses the PostgreSQL engine, and thus PostgreSQL syntax for SQL.

There is a PhpMinAdmin-type web-interface for manipulating the database.  There is also a Python DB API module.  The DB API module is described [on our site](http://www.rdbhost.com/howpython.html), as well as an intro
on using [SQLAlchemy to access SO data](http://rdbhost.blogspot.com/2010/02/sqlalchemy-and-stackoverflow-data-dump.html).

If you have any problems with it, please let me know at dkeeney@rdbhost.com.

*Update, June 8:* The data dump account on has been updated again yesterday with the June 1st data dump.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why is this being downvoted?

Comment: Because it's spam?

Comment: @Downvoter *Is* it spam? I don't know, I don't know the customs around here.

Comment: it's not spam per se but it would probably work better as an answer to an existing question rather than a standalone Q.

Comment: I suggest removing the three links on the bottom, they are just spam and add no information to this announcement.

Comment: @jeffatwood I have in the past used answering to post notices, and can return to doing so for future notices.  However, I would like to point out that there is plenty of precedent for using meta questions for announcement purposes.  I found these examples quickly, and include one question prominent on the front page right now:   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22869/stackql-yet-another-data-dump-sandbox  
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9863/track-your-reputation

Comment: I claim "no spam" and voted up. It's a direct link to the interface, and the only "advertisement" on that page is a small logo. You should remove the blog link, but other than that, it's fine. Thanks for providing this!

Comment: @balpha: the presence of advertisements shouldn't indicate whether it's spam or not (unless it's a page full of them, ofc). I don't think it's spam and I wouldn't think it was if it had ads.

Comment: Yeah- how else to announce the presence of a highly targeted SO related resource?! It takes a lot of effort to produce these tools for yall and iffn ya keep throwing shade by calling spam we producers might just find better uses for our time. Capisce? ;-)

Comment: Does this still exist ? Link 404s.

Answer (score 1):

The stackoverflow data dump account on rdbhost.com has been updated to include the April data dump, with data through March 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The stackoverflow data dump account on rdbhost.com has been updated again yesterday with data from the latest (June) datadump.

Now, the account has a customized stackoverflow 'look'.

Comment: You can update the question with these details (it'll also bump it to the front page so people will notice) rather than posting answers.  I'll edit the question to show you want I mean, and then you can delete these answers.