# Data Dump Sandboxen

Tags: discussion, data-dump, community-data

It appears that `http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/` is not in good working order.

Any other SQL data-dump sandboxes available?

Answer (score 8):

### List of data-dump sandboxes

- [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/stack-exchange-data-explorer) ( https://data.stackexchange.com/ )
- [Ozarific SQL Server](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/querying-the-stackoverflow-data-dump/)
- [RdbHost: Postgresqlicious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39354/stackoverflow-data-dump-feb-version-available-on-rdbhost) ([Rdbhost](http://www.rdbhost.com/rdbadmin/main.html), requires registration)

Comment: Ozarific, hahaha, nice.  I do allow interactive queries though.