# Is there a way to know which question/answer is linked to a badge on my own profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Is there a way to know which question/answer is linked to a badge on my own profile?

I just won a necromancer badge and I don't know from which one.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible.

And it's not something they are going to do.

see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101) for the reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the badge on your profile page. It will list the question(s/answer(s)) for which you've received that badge.

**Note:** (I believe) this only works for badges that are tied to specific posts, but it doesn't seem to work for all of them (doesn't seem to work for Disciplined, but it could be related to deleting the post/having-vs-not-having 19k rep).

Comment: Yep, [this works just fine now](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer?userid=40868) - guess this question should be changed to [meta-tag:status-completed] :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you look at your reputation history to see which answer recently reached the 5 upvote mark?

Not a perfect solution, but you should be able to find which answer earned you the badge.

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple method other than doing some detective work on your own. This is definitely something that would be nice, IMHO.

Comment: I pretty much agree, but it's been so over discussed in the past I can't even be bothered to explain why I agree. Oh well. Maybe it'll happen one day =:-)