# What do you guys think is the main motivation factor for people to answer in SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, polling, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Do you care more about reputation or badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26473/do-you-care-more-about-reputation-or-badges)
>   [What motivates people to answer questions in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/what-motivates-people-to-answer-questions-in-stack-overflow)

What do you guys think that the main motivation factor for the users to visit and answer SO?

Most people visit to find answers to their problems/questions, but people who answer what is the main motivation? Is it...

1. Reputation
2. Knowledge Sharing
3. Learning
4. etc...

At least tell whats your motivation for visiting these sites.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26473/do-you-care-more-about-reputation-or-badges

Comment: The size of their rep-peen

Comment: Earlier duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/what-motivates-people-to-answer-questions-in-stack-overflow

Comment: One other thing I probably missed in the list is `Finding Duplicates` :-) . I thought it will prompt me saying that it is a duplicate so just lazy searching before.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone will tell you it's the altruistic sensation you feel when helping people... but the real reason is reputation and badges.

<sup><sub>and pleasing the unicorn god</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

In my case, boredom.

Comment: At close to 2^16 rep, you must be *really* bored.

Comment: Have you thought about changing something in your life?