# Private statistics page for users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, statistics, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show How Much Statistics Left Until Badge Can Be Earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30902/show-how-much-statistics-left-until-badge-can-be-earned)

I'd like a new tab in my profile with different statistics, for example, what is my question/answer vote ratio, how many consecutive days have I come to the site, etc.

The intent is to have more visibility as to how far am I from the badges related to those numbers.

Accepted rate could also be listed here.
What else would you like to see? Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30902/show-how-much-statistics-left-until-badge-can-be-earned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is odd... there statistics aren't huge motivating factors for me, but these (and many like it) are raised frequently on meta.

Personally I'm happy with it just as it is - but I guess Jeff and the team have some "fun" calls to make, balancing what frequent users want, vs what is *needed* to provide a good tech site, get questions / new users / etc. I wonder if scrutinising lots of stats like this isn't the wrong way to go (or DIY from the data dump), and a slippery slope to lots of "just one more" numbers that don't in any way improve the questions or answers on the site.

(to balance that though, I suspect I've voted for more questions than answers lately, ahem)

Answer (score 4):

I'd love the idea of more detailed usage statistics. I can't help it. Some people play flash games for days to earn a gazillion worthless points and advance hundreds of XP levels; collect amulets, rings, crystals, potions to gain extra skill multipliers and what not.

Guess there's something in the human nature to *like* statistics. Good statistics are a proof of a person's awesomeness, right? ;)

I don't waste much time playing games, but when I do waste time on SO (which I sometimes really do), then I'd like to see that I am awesome. Rep points are fine. Badges are nice. Wouldn't mind having a personal stats page available to bask in my SO "accomplishments".

(to make matters clear, I certainly do see Marc Gravell's point "[...] that don't in any way improve the questions or answers on the site". I can only agree with that. But, hey, still...)

Comment: now, please, upvote :)