# How do I find out how many of my votes are for questions rather than answers?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page

We are being asked to vote on questions more often, however from a user’s profile page you can only see how many up and down votes they have done, you can’t see how the voting splits between questions and answers

Comment: Doesn't this go for a lot of badge related statistics? Like how many edits I performed or consecutive days logged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, You can't.

Maybe this is something the Stack Overflow API should address.

If you're polling your own vote information for the API, you should be able to get this information.

Comment: The thing is, the only reason you would care is to judge your progress towards the Electorate badge, and policy is that badges should come as a surprise...

Answer (score 1):

[George](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38941/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-of-my-votes-are-for-questions-rather-than-answers/38942#38942) is right, there's no way.

Well, there is a way, but it is more theoretical in nature. You could call

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/QUESTIONNUMBER/votes
```

for *every* question, while providing your correction authentication information. That call returns a JSON object like this:

```
[{"PostId":38942,"VoteTypeId":2},{"PostId":38941,"VoteTypeId":2}]
```

This is what *my* call for this very meta question returned. It means that I upvoted the question (38941) and George's answer (38942). VoteTypeId is 2 for upvotes and 3 for downvotes.

If you call it with a question ID, it returns both votes on the question and votes on answers to this question (which you can distinguish because it has a different number than the question). If you call it with an answer ID, it only returns the vote for this answer.

You should of cause be doing this slowly, so you don't get **banned** for excessive calls. Restricting this to questions in your active tags could at least give you an estimate on your question vote / answer vote ratio.

But then again, as I said, this is more theoretical.

<sub>Disclaimer: This answer is not endorsed (and is probably being frowned upon) by stackoverflow.com llc or U.S. Air.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps this answer will make them consider this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35421