# Show a Users upvotes and downvotes grouped by questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, voting, information-display

We should be able to see what the total count is for upvoted questions and up voted answers and vice versa. Right now it just takes a composite and shows total upvotes and total downvotes (on the profile page).

Comment: I think that this question is distinct from the proposed duplicate ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35421/private-statistics-page-for-users ). This one seem to be asking for a modest upgrade to the public statistics.

Answer (score 5):

Yes we should. It would also be nice to see other stats for a user, such as number of close votes given (split by questions still closed, and questions that have since been open), number of delete votes given, number of edits performed, etc.

Some of this information might be available from the API, and therefore could be built into greasemonkey scripts.

(This all been suggested before, though.)

Comment: (and it will all be suggested again.)