# Electorate hates me

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, electorate-badge

This is normally only a problem for political candidates, but it now impacts badges.

Maybe I've been too "suckered" by the hollow attraction of shiny pixelated bling, but alas the electorate badge still eludes me on stackoverflow.

You'd think that with over 8k of votes cast it would be a pinch, but alas no. But I'm pretty sure that I'm *way* over the 25% "question" votes required.

Don't make me pout! Why, stackoverflow, oh why?

Comment: I have the same issue - I am voting like crazy on questions and would have thought that I was over the magical line already.

Comment: Looking into this - wouldn't want you to not have your shiny :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There was a small bug in the SQL that grants this badge - it's been fixed and your badge has been awarded.

Thanks for finding this!

Comment: Nice, I saw another 21 people got Electorate badges too.

Comment: Cool; now have badge, thanks. Of course, you've just used positive reinforcement to train me that whingeing gets results ;-p

Comment: @Marc -- I believe I know the correction they made: `select ... where ... or isWhining = 1` :-)  BTW, thanks to you, I now have it as well.

Comment: I still don't have it... I guess I have to go vote on some questions...

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon: I think mine may still be un-fixed.  I'm at nearly 700 votes, and I am almost certain that 25% of these were on questions...  Can someone at least tell me if I am close or if it's not working properly for me?  Oh yah, it's on Superuser.com.

Comment: @nicorellius: You have to vote on *600 questions* and 25% of your total number of votes has to be on questions. You see the difference?

Comment: Apparently there's still an issue. I wasn't sure if I had enough votes, but now that you can see the breakdown, I'm quite sure: 924 Votes Cast all time 922 up 2 down 592 question 332 answer.

Comment: @Kendrick - you have to vote on 600 questions, not 592 :)

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon Ah... I thought the wording was just funny, and suggesting you had to vote on 600 questions/answers, with 25% of those being questions.  Thanks for the response, and not making fun of my reading comprehension issues :-)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the electorate badge penalizes long-time users with a history of voting more for answers.    Such is life :(

Answer (score 7):

Consider yourself as being in a penal colony.  Eventually you will be released, and given a worthless shiny trinket.  Or you will die there.  The period of servitude will reflect your past behaviour.

If you do make it out, StackOverflow/wherever will consider that you have done your time and have become a reformed voter, one who appreciates the dangers of imbalanced voting.  You will be a better person.

Comment: +1 for humor...I'm having a flash back to some trek movie or another. Must have been even numbered because aside from a couple of good lines I think it sucked. [voice type="manly klingon"]"Work well and you will be treated well. Work poorly and you will die.[/voice]

Comment: @dmckee: Um, I hate to just contribute to this geekfest, but do you really mean that it "must have been even numbered because...it sucked"?  Dude, the even numbered ones are the (relatively) good ones.  The odd ones are the ones that blew.

Comment: ::blinks:: Uh...Yeah. `s/odd/even/g`

Comment: "Consider yourself as being in a penal colony" - so that's why Australia wins a disproportionate number of gold medals at the Olympics!

Answer (score 4):

You may have voted mostly answers, I have the same problem.

But now I don't vote on answers at all!

EDIT:
Finally I can vote on answers again! (on meta at least)

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so7.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so7.png)

Comment: ... which is exactly why I think the electorate badge sucks - it discourages from voting for answers in order to fulfil the 25% quota.

Comment: Well, ~50 days of ~20 question votes gives 1000 which should help tip the scales. And I tend to vote for questions that I've found interesting and answered. Which is a fair few. Hence I *think* I should be well above 25%... impossible to tell for sure, though.

Comment: @Pekka - I don't see it quite that way; there *is* value in the questions too, so I'm happy to focus on rewarding questions for a while.

Comment: Here's another question for you to vote on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35421

Comment: Not voting on answers is demonstrating a lack of community just as much as not voting on questions is. Please just vote on things that deserve it, and let the stats take care of themselves.

Comment: I just saw who wrote the accepted answer, small world

Comment: @Downvoter - it seems I've already voted on that one. Maybe not in the direction you'd prefer.... but I've got "electorate" on meta, so I can vote for your answer instead ;-p

Comment: @Ether, I just do what the system wants me to do...

Comment: @Marc there is value in questions, totally, I also can see the motivation behind the badge: Make people vote more on questions. Great. But the quota thing screws it up IMO, because it discourages voting for answers in certain constellations. It should be more like "has voted on at least x number of questions, and y number of answers."

Comment: And I stand by that - I'm not sure we need to see every stat in existence on the site.

Comment: So @Marc, you downvoted me and I accepted your answer... that's not fair at all! (I feel used)

Comment: Why? I *told* you I didn't really agree...

Comment: One thing is to suspect, another to know... (and I'm just kidding)

Comment: The thing the electorate badge has done for me is encourage me to downvote marginal questions whenever they have an answer I really want to vote for. Afterall, I sure as heck ain't going to upvote undeserving dreck...

Comment: @Ether:  <wail>But it's a GOLD BADGE!!!!</wail>.  You expect me to serve the community at the expense of a gold badge?  Typically, people will do what they're given incentives to do, and SO is no exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
 >>> ((7828 + 425) * .25) / 25
 82.530000000000001
```

So, you need ~83 continuous days to votes on questions with 25 votes on each day.

Comment: Assuming I've never voted on a question... which is *very* far from true.

Comment: I meant ~83 as upto 83 actually. :-)