# Information about expanded usercards in the 'create posts' privilege page refers to a drop shadow which is no longer present

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, help-center, user-card

In the [create posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) privilege in [the Help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) it says (emphasis mine):

> ### Expanded usercards
>
> When anyone is viewing your usercard on a question, an answer, or on the users list, they may hover over your avatar to produce an expanded usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a hover card.
>
> [image]
>
> An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 6 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile. **When your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard a drop shadow effect will be shown on your avatar.**
>
> [image]

---

This is how the normal/expanded usercard [now looks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40445/284827) (note that there's no drop shadow effect):

> [image]

The drop shadows on avatars that can be expanded [is no longer present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336681/284827) (and is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)): [Aaron Shekey ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2804712/aaron-shekey) said in [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390765/1364007) to [Expanded Usercards are not Showing Drop-shadow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390764/1364007) that

> This intentional, but not ideal at the moment. I plan on having a preview card on every user. In my opinion, it's weird UX having it on some users and not all, regardless of a drop shadow or a bio.

As it's intentional behaviour, can the page in the Help center be updated to not refer to a drop shadow that isn't there?

Comment: It's unfortunate that there used to be a visual indicator, and now there isn't, even though only some profiles expand- I wish it would've been removed *after* making every profile expandable. It's weird UI to have only some expand without the visual cue, I'd never noticed that it was based on whether a user had content in their bio.

Comment: A note: the expanded user card only shows if the user has a bio that has at least 6 characters. There was also a past bug where it wouldn't show on users whose bios were automatically filled in when joining the site (it was fixed, but not retroactively for profiles already affected). I did file a [prior request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341689/reinstate-the-drop-shadow-on-user-cards-in-cases-where-the-user-card-shows) asking for it to be reinstated since it still wasn't always shown, but that was heavily downvoted and I had to delete it (it would have been auto-deleted anyway).

Comment: Related: ["Create posts" privilege page lists incorrect minimum character length (in "About me" summary) required for expanded usercard to be shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379308/335251). Feel free to let me know if there are any other changes we need to make to this Help Center page / this text (...since it seems like we could just spin it off into a separate Help Center page of its own) as well.

Comment: @V2Blast The information was previously in the established user privilege page, then was moved to the create posts privilege page when the reputation requirement was dropped from 1,000 to 1. As far as other improvements, it would be nice to have a link to [this bug report](/posts/comments/1182040) that explains that due to a bug, profiles will not show an expanded user card if they were created before April 2021, automatically filled in when joining, and never edited since. Also, I do agree that it should be split off into a separate help center page.

Comment: I also still believe that reinstating the shadow to visually differentiate whether there will be a popup or not is important. I think the community of today is likely to receive it better than the community of 2018, and I'm now more experienced in coming up with strong arguments for requests. Is it OK if I repost a new copy of the same request that has an improved argument? I want to be sure I have explicit staff approval.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Well, you're welcome to make that request, but I can't say how it'll be received by the community, or whether we're likely to implement it. (And yeah, you're right about the info being moved over from the "established user" privilege page; I edited one of my comments on the issue I linked above to point that out.)

Comment: @V2Blast Wasn't referring to community reception or whether it'll actually get implemented, but rather that I wouldn't be violating site rules against reposting deleted content. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed this section, since it's no longer relevant. Thanks for pointing that out!

---

However, as Sonic pointed out in the comments – and I agreed – it didn't really make sense for this to be on a privilege-specific page anymore, since [it was made available to everyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334941/335251) in 2020 (rather than being limited to those with the [established user](/help/privileges/established-user) privilege, as it was when [the feature was originally added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810/335251) back in 2011).

As such, I actually ended up removing the info about expanded user cards from the [create posts](/help/privileges/create-posts) privilege page, and creating a new Help Center page specifically about this feature: [How does the User Card popup work?](/help/expanded-user-card)

If there are any links out there (e.g. in FAQs) that currently point to the old page for more info about this feature, please update them as necessary. Thanks again!