# "Create posts" privilege page lists incorrect minimum character length (in "About me" summary) required for expanded usercard to be shown

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, help-center, user-card

When the expanded user cards privilege was made universal, the minimum summary comment length was [reduced from 28 characters down to 6](/a/342575/1099857) in 2020.

However, the [create posts page](/help/privileges/create-posts) in the help center still lists the minimum as 28 characters:

> Replace [your text here] with your desired summary (of at least **28 characters**)

[emphasis added]

Can the help center be updated to reflect this change?

Comment: The images are also wrong. I don't think any profiles show the shadow effect.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not entirely sure it makes sense for this to be under "create posts". I understand it was probably just moved to the existing 1-reputation privilege page, but it seems disjoint from the rest of information on the page and is very hard to find by looking at the top-level [/privileges](/help/privileges) page. I don't know if it's a significant enough feature to warrant its own 1-rep entry though (_e.g._ [this terribly worded mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mak44.png)) or just changing the existing summary... though that's likely a separate conversation.

Comment: @Laurel hey, I have effect everywhere! :-D

Comment: It looks like Yaakov moved this section to the "create posts" privilege help page from the "established user" privilege help page at the same time this character limit was lowered from 28 to 6 (both changes to the usercard feature happened around the same time). Higher up in the "create posts" help page, it does correctly state the character limit, so I'm guessing Yaakov just didn't realize this character requirement was mentioned again later in the same section.

Comment: (That said, I agree that it seems weird for this to be attached to the "create posts" privilege; honestly, it's sort of weird that this is a "privilege" at all... And it seems like [other staff agreed when the drop-shadow aspect was removed in 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390765/1478931): "I plan on having a preview card on every user. In my opinion, it's weird UX having it on some users and not all, regardless of a drop shadow or a bio." Of course, that hasn't actually happened yet, and Aaron Shekey left the company last year... But I still agree with that idea.)

Comment: Related: [Information about expanded usercards in the 'create posts' privilege page refers to a drop shadow which is no longer present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361743/335251). Feel free to let me know if there are any other changes we need to make to this Help Center page / this text (...since it seems like we could just spin it off into a separate Help Center page of its own) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the outdated number in this line (and removed the section about the [drop shadow that no longer appears](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361743/335251)). Thanks for pointing that out!

---

However, as you pointed out in the comments – and I agreed – it didn't really make sense for this to be on a privilege-specific page anymore, since [it was made available to everyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334941/335251) in 2020 (rather than being limited to those with the [established user](/help/privileges/established-user) privilege, as it was when [the feature was originally added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810/335251) back in 2011).

As such, I actually ended up removing the info about expanded user cards from the [create posts](/help/privileges/create-posts) privilege page, and creating a new Help Center page specifically about this feature: [How does the User Card popup work?](/help/expanded-user-card)

If there are any links out there (e.g. in FAQs) that currently point to the old page for more info about this feature, please update them as necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: It would be nice if there were a link to [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1182040) in the help center page - prior to April 2021, there was a bug where profiles that were automatically filled in when joining the site and never edited since wouldn't show expanded popups, and the fix for that bug was **not** retroactive (as in, profiles filled in when automatically joining the site prior to April 2021 and never edited since will still not show an expanded usercard today even if they're otherwise long enough to have one).