# Why do I not yet have the Fanatic badge?

Tags: support, activity-badges

I think I've been visiting the site continuously for the required amount of time to receive the  Fanatic badge, but I haven't received it yet. How do I find out how long I have left to go?

Comment: Oh, my SO account is here if required: http://stackoverflow.com/users/102482/finglas

Comment: Counting the log it appears to be 92 days, I had some rouge day in early November. How I survived a day without SO I don't know. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: *> had some rouge day in early November. How I survived a day without SO I don't know.* You probably did log into SO on that day, but because the site is set to GMT, you did not log in that day in SO’s opinion even though to you, you did. `:-|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you flag one of your posts, a moderator could let you know via email.

Steps:

- **Flag** on of your posts as "Requires Moderator Attention".
- **Type**: I think I should have fanatic badge by now, am I missing any days?
- You'll either get a response as a comment in that post, or they may even email you.

Comment: So flag as require moderator attention and explain/link to this question? Are you sure about this?

Comment: Yea.  An SO mod can check your activity.  (I can only check it on Meta)

Comment: Cheers guys, will do.

Comment: You don't even have to flag this post, just a post you've made.

Comment: Is this the official recommended way of contacting a moderator? O_o

Comment: Don't thy have better things to do?  This seems like a much better thing to have set up as a simple setting/calculation in your profile.  Every time the job runs to try to calculate it it could update your entry.

Comment: @tim, vote this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35421

Comment: @downvoter - done.  voted up that one and another one.

Answer (score 5):

You were sorely missed on Nov 25th:

```
Finglas -> User accessed site Nov 28 at 17:41
Finglas -> User accessed site Nov 27 at 12:20
Finglas -> User accessed site Nov 26 at 8:35
Finglas -> User accessed site Nov 24 at 8:46
Finglas -> User accessed site Nov 23 at 9:43
```

(edited slightly to remove IP and any irrelevant entries)