# How do I know if I've reached my daily rep cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

As the title says: how do I know if I've reached my daily rep cap? Is there a simple yes/no indicator at least? Even better, is there a place where I can see "this is how many rep points left that you can claim today that is subject to the cap"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays the answer is obvious: go to [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and look for the `[..]` for that day.

> *Jeff Atwood said*: If the value is capped, it will appear in brackets like `[3]` so.

#### References

- [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Comment: So i would have to pass the cap, not only reach it, to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

You can click the envelope next to your name in the top of this page, click **Today** and if you have less than 200 reputation points earned, you still haven't reached the cap.

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so6.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so6.png)

Comment: So if it says 199, then I still haven't reached the cap and I can still earn 1 more point? It's not the case that perhaps I've already reached the cap but then lost a point due to a downvote, for example?

Comment: And how come I've seen 210+ points in a day before? That can only happen if the number also counts the exempt points, right? But if that number is a mix between the exempt points and the capped points, then 200 doesn't always mean that the cap has been reached, right?

Comment: Accepted answers can get you over 200, but technically you've reached the cap

Comment: @user: There are not two pool of points. If you start the day by collecting 195 points in acceptances and bounties (exempt) you will only be allowed to get 5 points on upvotes (non-exempt), so order matters and if you got the upvotes first and the acceptances later you would have come out further ahead. This is just one of a whole pile of odd seeming edge cases in the rep system that result from a highly local implementation.

Comment: @user: another of those edge case is that 199 might represent 200 (hit the cap) then downvoted someone. But you're still capped for the day.

Comment: @Downvoter, @dmckee, see my own answer =)

Answer (score 3):

Shortly after the *first* time that happens you'll be awarded the `Mortarboard` badge.

Comment: What about the rest of the time? Can I see a number, perhaps, of how many times I've reached the cap? I'm basically trying to get the related badges (epic and legendary), so to see that number going up will be nice.

Comment: @user, vote on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35421

Comment: That question is a duplicate. You should instead upvote this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30902/show-how-much-statistics-left-until-badge-can-be-earned and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found out that the Downvoter's method is not 100% reliable. I appreciate his effort in creating the picture, so I made my own (note: question titles are greyed out in this picture).

http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5019/13467900.png

As you can see, according to the summary, I gained 193 points of reputation yesterday. This could mean that I may be able to get 7 more points. However, if you look at the itemized list, you see that I did not get any points for the last two items, since I've already reached my cap.

So I think this is the definitive way of telling if you've reached your cap or not: **when you go to your Reputation/Today tab and see items you no longer get points for**. In this case, even if the tab title says that you have < 200 points, you're guaranteed to have already reached your cap.

Note that this is a sufficient but not necessary condition, but that's fine if you want to be safe.

Comment: You cast 7 downvotes yesterday, apparently.

Comment: Actually I was also downvoted by others, so it's a bit more complicated than that. And that's my point: that total number alone is ambiguous. It could've been reached in many different ways, and need not necessarily tell you if you've reached your cap or not. Looking at the itemized list is the safest way to go. It can yield false negative, but never a false positive.

Comment: Order matters. Once you hit two hundred any way round, non-exempt positive points do not count, but non-exempt negative points do as do exempt points. You could have been capped and then lost 7 points somehow. I believe that that still counts towards the badges. BTW--Why he effort to hide your identity?

Comment: Not really trying to hide my identity, but I just filled in my SO username here if that's any better.

Comment: Do you know that you can associate accounts? That makes it easy for people to find you across site boundaries *and* gives you a 100 point bonus (assuming you have at least 200 points on the parent account). Go to you profile in the "accounts" tab.