# Why no Mortarboard for me?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-badges

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40714/how-do-i-know-if-ive-reached-my-daily-rep-cap), my Recent page on StackOverflow shows I have gained 221 reputation today. So why don't I have the Mortarboard badge?

[image]

Comment: Please stand by, adding freehand circles

Comment: Where did you get that email icon next to your name ?

Comment: At the top. Where there is a link to your profil page with your rep and badges. To the left of your name there is an email Icon.

Comment: That's a really old screen capture @returnPhaDaPhunk :-) That was what SE had before the multicollider thingadongdong.

Comment: Oooo I see... Thanks !

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd it's called "The Envelope" don't insult it by calling it "email icon"! It used to become red when there were new notifications and everyone loved it until its [cruel death](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages). ;)

Comment: @sha ... im.. sorry.. I didnt know..

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd you are forgiven! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes it takes a bit for the badges to appear. As far as I know badges are calculated every few hours and awarded then.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I got it *instantly* on SuperUser, so I assumed it was instant.

Comment: I ended up getting the badge a few hours later just as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since some changes last month the reputation for accepted answers doesn't any longer count for the reputation cap. The answers on the question you linked to are no longer up to date.

For Mortarboard you now need 200 reputation from votes alone. For example 20 upvotes on answers, or more if there also were downvotes.

If you get upvotes that are "capped" by the limit you will see that the vote count shown in the "Recent Activity" items doesn't match the reputation shown for them anymore, like the top two ones here:

[image: capped]
<sub>(source: [tejp.de](http://tejp.de/files/linked/img/so-replimit.png))</sub>

Comment: Ahhhhhh. That was it. Of my +226 rep, 30 was from accepted answers.

Comment: @Josh: doh, you missed it by 4!

Answer (score 2):

**It is not true**, you earn 'Mortarboard' if you earn 200 Reputation.

**But**

 this reputation should be **Hand earned**(*Earned by posting Either Good questions or Good Answers*).

**Example:**
It shouldn't contain **Bonus** reputation like we get +100 Rep after making 200 Reputation.
Yes, it takes some time to award you a badge, but **it will be yours** only if you have your own Reputation.