# Mortarboard badge not awarded for 200 reputation in a day

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why no Mortarboard for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45870/why-no-mortarboard-for-me)

I got more than 200 reputation on Stack Overflow today but didn't get the Mortarboard badge. I was so excited to finally get it but then - nothing :( How come? Is there a bug?

Comment: You have to wait until midnight UTC. See [this FAQ answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 200 points from **votes alone** to gain `Mortarboard` badge. Accepting answers for your own questions which brings you **+2** points don't count.

See this post: [Why no Mortarboard for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45870/why-no-mortarboard-for-me)

Another post (*from diamond moderator*): [Why don't I have the 'Mortarboard' badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100512/why-dont-i-have-the-mortarboard-badge) It clearly states **+2** from accepts don't count to avoid gaming the system.

You have quite a few accepted answers. <strike>If my math is correct, at the time of posting this you have only **170** points from upvotes. You still need 30 points to get `Mortarboard` badge.</strike> Looks like you just crossed the threshold to receive the `Mortarboard` badge.

Your reputation page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/561309/laurent?tab=reputation

Comment: Strange, the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) says accepted answers *do* count (accepted *questions*, however, do not). Who's right here? :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Please note that I have added another link.

Comment: I think I misunderstood `accepted answers` (I was thinking of the `+15` type rather than the `+2` type). Your answer is correct.

Comment: lol I had kept all these non-accepted answers for the day I'll be near 200, but looks like they thought of that :D How about the points awarded for editing wiki tags? The FAQ doesn't mention these?

Comment: @Laurent: Sorry, not sure about wiki tags but looks like you just crossed the threshold to receive the `Mortarboard` badge.

Comment: Yes thanks, I just got it. It looks like I didn't have to wait till midnight UTC.

Comment: In the first sentence the "from votes alone" is quite misleading, as accepted answers on someone else's question also count