# Comparing your personal stats against a badge requirement

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

I would like a way to see how much more I need to "work" or "improve" to get a badge.

Let's say that I want the Commentator badge. When I hover over it, it would be great if it could say something like:

> Comment on 10 questions. Your stats: 5/10 comments.

Even better would be a whole page that presented a table to compare all badges with your current stats.

Comment: See also [Electorate, Pundit, etc badge progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress), [Show How Much Statistics Left Until Badge Can Be Earned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30902/show-how-much-statistics-left-until-badge-can-be-earned) and [SO Badge Progress Report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report) (that last one also hosts one of the Jeff answers that Cody mentions in his answer). Notably, the one that this is a duplicate of has been declined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it turns out that you're in luck! We have such a site where you can do exactly that. It's called the **[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)**, and it allows you to run queries on the public data dumps.

Many of the queries that have already been written and shared focus on evaluating your progress towards particular badges. And if you can't find the query you want, you can write your own.

For example, [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/540/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress) shows you the progress you've made towards earning the `Pundit` badge.

As far as integrating these features into the site itself (e.g., seeing the count when you hover over a badge, as you mention), that's unlikely to happen. Jeff [has said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440) a [couple of times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report) that [badges are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/101#101) supposed to incite curiosity and it won't always be immediately obvious how you've earned them.

Comment: However, you should remember that the data explorer data is not real-time. It's refreshed every month or so, so the query will not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 7):

Some information is discoverable on your profile page, for example:

- You can see how close you are to the tag badges as the score is shown next to the badge name (1)
- You can see how close you are to the Civic Duty badge and Electorate badge as the total votes cast and the break down between question and answer votes is now shown (2)

[image: discoverable badge progress]

(You just have to do the maths).

Other information (votes on question and answers, number of days you've exceeded the rep cap etc.) is also available in different places. You just have to go hunting.