# Add "traceability" to badges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

I have often the problem that I don't know why I got a badge and it's somewhere between painful and impossible to track what I have done to earn it.
It would be really nice if there would be a page where you can see what contributed to a specific badge (which questions/answers/votes/days of visit/...)

There seems to be some kind of rule engine, so it should be possible to present the artifacts that triggered the rules.

Comment: I think this was already covered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge

Comment: The fact that the current badge process doesn't provide these information doesn't mean that it couldn't be added ;-)

Comment: I don't disagree. It would be a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not possible to track which question/answer results in a badge, then at least the notification should be changed to not direct you to your profile.  I mean, if the profile only shows that the badge has been awarded, what's the point?  The notification message just told you that.

Typically, if I'm currently on the system when it happens, I go to the notification summary page and see if there is a recent question/answer vote that seems to have triggered it.   Not the best solution, but I think it's all we have at present.

Answer (score 3):

I like the "surprise" element of badges, but I also like being able to find out where I got them from. The other day I got my second "Populist" badge. This is for giving an answer that is upvoted 10 times over the accepted answer. So getting this badge can happen if the questioner, months after the question is asked, finally accepts a lower-voted answer than mine. This makes it effectively impossible to find the question/answer.

So +1 for this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Very good idea, this has been bugging me too. There are a number of badges that make it very easy to find out what they were awarded for (`good answer`, `Guru`) but how do you track down the question you earned `tumbleweed` for?

Update: Ah, this has been discussed before and seems to be impossible to implement. Too bad.

Comment: It's not impossible to implement. It's just impossible to implement on top of the current database schema. They're different things.