# When exactly did I get this and that badge? Possibility to search/filter the Activity?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

It would be nice to have a timestamp of the (last) awarded badge in the badge tooltips in the user profile. This should be a non-trivial task since it's stored as `CreationDate` in the `badges` table. It would also be nice to provide a bit decent search filter in the *Activity* tab. It's currently hard to crawl in the history which goes past what's been displayed.

Comment: I guess this goes with this other question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge

Comment: @Gnoupi: Reread the question: the **timestamp**. I'm not interested in who and how. The badges table has a `CreationDate` column. That so-called dupe question doesn't suggest a filter in *Activity* tab as well.

Comment: Haven't said it was a duplicate, just said it was related. Even if I said it badly.

Comment: This is been marked as a dupe at the same moment you commented this. Well OK, maybe it's coincidence.

Comment: I guess the close vote and the comment merely coincided. This question *would* be covered if the other feature request was implemented (and I think we'd all prefer that), but for the time being, I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: @BalusC - I would need a bit more reputation to vote to close it. And I meant more that your suggestion would be something to improve this other feature request. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Ether: How many tabs do you have open? lol [JEFF THIS IS WHY WE NEED TO BE ABLE TO RESCIND CLOSE VOTES.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by @mmyers in a comment on Jonathan's answer, there's a **[badges]** tab in the **Recent Activity** page (which you can access by clicking the envelope icon on the left side of the top bar), which I completely overlooked at the moment I asked the question. To check the badges older than "last month", you only have to hassle with the `StartDate` and `EndDate` parameters in the URL since the date fields on the page are not modifiable. It's by the way limited on a timespan of 90 days.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You mean, you'd like a badge-history tab? :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [sampsonresume.com](http://sampsonresume.com/labs/stackoverflow/badge-history.gif))</sub>

Comment: I shocked, I thought that I missed a tab, but it's after all just a photoshop :) Something like that would be nice, but that's not needed. The information about the awarded context isn't available in the DB. Only the timestamp is and it seemed me a non-trivial task to put it in the tooltip of the badges in the main userprofile.

Comment: @BalusC How dare you credit photoshop for my mad HTML/CSS Firebug skills!!!!111!!Eleven!!

Comment: Whatever you like :)

Comment: If it were photoshop, I would have included some freehand circles ;)

Comment: Looks like Jonathan Sampson is teasing us with moderator only features.

Comment: How about http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/138231?Tab=Badges&StartDate=2010-04-01&EndDate=2010-04-19?

Comment: @mmyers: This doesn't go past last month. Hm well, you have to edit the `StartDate` and `LastDate` yourself.