# In Stack Overflow how can I see what for somebody got a badge for

Tags: support, badges

I have seen one user and I saw he has a golden badge, as this is more rare I wanted to see how he got it, or what for. But I couldn't find out. Is there a way to do this ?

**UPDATE:** On Mouse Over I don't see that.

But guess what I found the Badges Section at the bottom of the stats :D Thanks

Comment: Questions *about* this site are best asked at meta.stackoverflow.com... I have voted to migrate it there for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the user - and look in the 'Badges' section? :)

EDIT: On mouse over you get to see why he got the badge.

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://stackoverflow.com/badges

Answer (score 0):

While some badges may be awarded for a particular question or answer, a lot are very general so you can't get more precise than "been here for a year" in the mouseover.