# The badge notification in recent activity should have the same link as in profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, recent-activity

We now have a [nice system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge) to find out which question awarded which badge, in the profile page.

However, in the notifications, in recent activity, badges are still appearing with the older link, so without this feature. It probably would be nice to have it there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yerp, I think I agree. Deployed a fix.

Originally I thought that the badge would be at the top of the list anyway, but from a feature discovery point of view changing this makes total sense. This will entice people to click on badges from their profile page.

Comment: I just experienced your change. I got a "Great Question" badge for [this very feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge) :)