# Are we going to know what ALL our new badges are for?

Tags: discussion, badges

I just went to SuperUser and saw the following:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/badges.png

Is this new? (Not the badge, of course - the question the badge is for.)

Will all new badge notifications tell us which question we got it for?

Comment: Ahhhh, I finally have closure with Taxonomist!  Best.Enhancement.Ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also see that for (almost) all badges you have, clicking on them on your profile page.

Yes, it's new.

Comment: Yes!!!!!! I've wanted that for ages!

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge.