# No love for the Disciplined?

Tags: feature-request, badges, disciplined-badge

I just have to say, it's awesome that we are finally able to [find out which post awarded us a given badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge). [waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) deserves a reward of, well... waffles.

Now, I don't want to sound like I'm looking a gift-icorn in the mouth, but I noticed that the [Disciplined badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/35/disciplined) actually *doesn't* display the post the badge was awarded for. I assume this is due to the fact that the post which gave you the badge is now deleted, so no one should be able to see it listed anywhere.

I'm just wondering if there's any plan to eventually show this info to just the Disciplined badge earner and no one else? Or will that be either too difficult or otherwise undesirable to implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there was a deliberate design decision to hide this here.

On profile pages we hide the deleted questions, even if its a question you happen to have deleted AND you are looking at your profile page. So, to stay consistent I thought it makes sense to have badge awarded for deletions not show the reason. The reason is still stored in the database.

There is one minor exception, we do show a question link when you first receive the badge. But that is it.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a global reputation recalc... I think it's time for a:

### Global Badge Recalc!

i.e. clear everyone's badge counts, walk through the DB and re-award all badges according to the current state of the system. Badges corresponding to deleted questions/answers/comments, or votes since redacted, will be nullified and the badge counts will be accurate.

Comment: That probably wouldn't have much affect on the Disciplined badge, since you actually get the badge *upon deletion* of your own 3+ upvoted post. If one or more votes is somehow undone to drop it below 3, then the badge would be invalid. That said, this answer should actually be a stand-alone feature request, in which case I would upvote it hard and fast.

Comment: Done! I nominate your email for all questions about "where did my badges go?!?!" :)

Comment: @gnovice: yes, that would have to be a special case, as the badge is actually awarded for a deleted post, not an undeleted one.

Comment: @Jeff: bwahahahaha!