# Show question/answer for which a badge was awarded in recent activity

Tags: feature-request, badges, recent-activity

Since [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge), if you get a new badge you will see a notification in the alert bar saying "You've earned the [badge name] badge for [question/answer link]". I like this.

However, if you earn two or more badges, you just see "You've earned [badge name] and [n] other badges." <del>But as far as I can tell there's no way to find out what those badges were awarded for.</del> You can click on the badge in activity and recent activity, but IMHO that's not very intuitive. I'd like the question the badge was awarded for to be displayed in the following places.

If you click your envelope and look at the badges tab:

http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9840/recentactivitybadges.png

If you go to your profile and click the activity tab:

http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2614/activitybadges.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the badge to get more info, including when and for what it was awarded.

Comment: thanks, i assumed that did the same thing that clicking on a badge everywhere else does--show you a list of people who have gotten the badge recently. i still think it could be added to the two other areas i listed.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality exists, just not where you propose.  Go to your profile, scroll down to the end of the summary ("main page") and click on the badge you're interested in.  That'll list the relevant data for times you've personally earned the badge.

EDIT:
It actually looks like you can do some simple URL manipulation to see any user's badge info.  This link lets me see all of your Nice Answers:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?user_id=18511

You need only append `?user_id=[whatever]` to the usual badge URL for this.  The default for the way I mentioned earlier is your own ID, of course.

Comment: It works in the recent/badges and the activity sections too.

Comment: I never said otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the badge. It's a link to a page which will tell you which question/answer it applies to.

It works on either page.