# I was just awarded "Nice Answer and 1 other badge"... but which one?

Tags: feature-request, badges, recent-activity

As I logged on to SO today, I was met by the message

> You've earned "Nice Answer" and 1 other badge. See your profile.

"Nice!" I thought and started looking around. However, I don't keep track of each an every one of my badges, so finding out which one the other one is, is literally impossible. I know Jeff wants this to be like a scavenger hunt, but I don't see the point in awarding systems of different kinds if you don't even get to know what behavior you were awarded for.

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge), but that's about finding out *which post* awarded you a badge - in my case I just (at least to start with) am happy with knowing *which badge*.

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the activities tab on your profile and you should be able to see it. Looks like it was [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38055?tab=activity) awarded for [Cannot get T4MVC to work with VS2010 and ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906341/cannot-get-t4mvc-to-work-with-vs2010-and-asp-net-mvc-2)

On your activities page (already linked to) you can click on the badge and it will take you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question?userid=38055) which shows you what they were awarded for.