# Is there a way to view the order in which individual badges were earned?

Tags: feature-request, badges

When I go to look at badges in my profile (the "Activity" tab), I can order them by "recent", and voila, the badges are listed in order of most recently earned.

For badges which I can earn more than once (e.g. Nice Answer or Nice Question) that I have earned a times, the category is displayed at the point in which I earned the badge most recently, showing "Nice Question x a".

This can be helpful if I'm trying to figure out how many times I earned a badge (and you can still see it by re-arranging the badges in other ways, such as "class" and "name").

What if I want to see the order in which I earned each badge, regardless of the other times I earned it? Is there a way to see this?

I'd like to be able to see something like this, for example:

1. Nice Question
2. Nice Answer
3. Curious
4. Benefactor
5. Nice Question
6. . . .

[Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge?lq=1) is related, but I'm not talking about identifying a certain post with a certain badge.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to view the order in which individual badges were
>   earned?

Click on the badge in your profile, which takes you to a page with that badge and the number of times you earned it with the date of each time listed in reverse chronological order.

e.g.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=274942

Some people have earned certain badges many times over, but I doubt anyone needs or likely wants to be able to sort them by order, so the above is enough IMO.

Comment: I knew about this; I was focusing primarily on comparing a badge of a given type to a badge of another type.

Comment: "*I was focusing primarily of comparing a badge of a given type to a badge of another type*" Your question doesn't mention "compare" at all. In which case I'm not sure, does SEDE offer anything? (I've barely used it)

Comment: Sorry about that; I was unclear. I'll edit.